# Ubuntu cannot boot as black screen with blinking cursor on topleft corner

Tags: boot, networking, 16.04, grub2

I put my computer with power on for one night, and after waking up, ubuntu cannot boot, just a blink cursor on top-left corner.

But i can boot into live CD and windows, with network, so hardware should be OK.

Here are what i've tried:

1. `ctrl+alt+F1`, doesn't take any effect
2. try to edit grub2 menu with `no modeset`, `ctrl+alt+f1` still doesn't 
   take effect
3. boot into recovery mode as root prompts, but network seems down, cannot resolve any domain name, so `apt-get` cannot do anything
4. boot into live CD, network is OK. But if i `chroot` into my ubuntu on harddisk, network is down, cannot resolve any network and even `ifconfig` only shows `lo`, no `eth0`

Comment: Can you edit the grub menu and replace 'quiet splash' with 'text' and tell us if you see anything?

Comment: Excellent! With your suggestion i finally can see console, and seems network is OK. But i still don't know what to do. `Black screen with cursor on the top-left corner` always reminds me of nvidia drivers corrupted. So i ran `apt-get purge nvidia*` & `apt-get install nvidia-current-updates`. But after all this i still got black screen with cursor

Comment: Now i purge `nvidia*` and install `nvidia-common`, system boot but with `low-graphics mode`. I'm trying to figure out what's wrong

Comment: well, delete `etc/X11/xorg.conf.failsafe` and `service lightdm restart`, i can boot into ubuntu, but after rebooting, it's still no good

Comment: If you purging things anyway, might as well get rid of xorg too, 'sudo apt-get remove --purge xserver-xorg-video-nouveau xserver-xorg-video-nv' and reinstall everything and then reboot.

Comment: Well, i just install `nvidia-common` and now PC boot up. but if i install `nvidia-current-updates`, it will enter into black screen, don't know why but now at least my PC is working now

Comment: `nividia-current` is to be used for legacy hardware only. What Nivida model do you have?

Comment: How to check it?

Comment: `lspci` should show it and that's something you **need** to know before attempting any troubleshooting. Some older Nvidia cards work **up to** a certain driver version only and other newer ones work with drivers **of a certain version or newer**. Installing the wrong driver often results in exactly what you're seeing now.

Comment: It's  Quadro K1100M